# FusionCharts - Using both 'label' and 'labelLink' for separate actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, fusioncharts

Using json for my datasource and I would like to have the bars in the graph drill with the use of linkedCharts via the `link` attribute and would like for the labels of the graph to do something else (specifically to list all the items that are represented in the bar in the graph.) via the `labelLink`.

For example, in the fiddle by FusionCharts themselves (http://fiddle.jshell.net/fusioncharts/k1s6y3qp/) if I edit the chart data to look like the following;

```
"data": [{
    "label": "Apple",
    "value": "810000",
    "link": "newchart-xml-apple",
    "labelLink": "j-foo"
}, {
    "label": "Cranberry",
    "value": "620000",
    "link": "newchart-xml-cranberry",
    "labelLink": "j-bar"
},{...}]
```

Both the chart elements and the labels load the new chart in the `link` attribute, seemingly ignoring the `labelLink`, but if there is no `link` attribute the `labelLink` works as expected;
error `Uncaught foo() is not a function` in console.

Is there any way I can have the `link` act on the graph separately from the `labelLink` for the label of that graph item instead of both the graph and label using the same function?

Comment: Doesn't look like there is an easy way. Perhaps you can use the `beforeLinkedItemOpen` event hook?

Comment: Kind of annoying since I had it working at one point on one chart, questioned whether everyone would like them to work that way, and now that same chart does what I've described above.
But now cannot figure out what's changed, or what I'd done inadvertently to break it so that it worked correctly.

Attempting to fudge it with the `dataLabelClick` event but cannot prevent it from still drilling further...

Comment: So, it was updating the library that caused it...
This worked perfectly fine in v3.10.1, but not 3.11.0 or 3.11.2.

Comment: Ha, so a good case for a [bug report](http://forum.fusioncharts.com/forum/4-bug-reports/).